# How do I select more than one file in LaunchBar?

Tags: launchbar

Is it possible to select multiple files in LaunchBar?  (For example, I may want to select two files in a folder and "drag" them to another folder.)  How do I do that?

Comment: If this is possible it's pretty cool. I have a feeling it is not. I couldn't find a way to select multiple files from a LaunchBar file search. All key+select operations I tried just selected one file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**An update for LaunchBar 6**

Version 6.0 introduced a slick way of selecting multiple items. The LaunchBar folks call it the “Sixth Sense”. Selected items are held in a “staging area” and can be acted upon all at once using typical LaunchBar tools.

- Typing Command-A will select all items in the search list.
- Typing a Comma (“,”) will select the current item and allow you to move on to select more.
- Pressing Shift will scrolling up or down with the arrow keys select continuously as you scroll
- You can undo these actions by repeating them with a selected file. Hitting Escape clears the selections.

The selection then works with other actions: Press Tab to send them to another folder, etc.

There’s a discussion at the [LaunchBar blog](https://blog.obdev.at/post/the-sixth-sense/)

Answer (score 7):

I found [a post on the Objective Development Forums](http://forums.obdev.at/viewtopic.php?p=7742#p7742) that suggests a different approach:

1. Select the file to move or copy (either in the Finder, or in LaunchBar).
2. Copy it (⌘-C)
3. Select another file (again, either in the Finder, or in LaunchBar).
4. Use ClipMerge (Press ⌘-C twice.)
5. Repeat steps 3 & 4 if you wish to select more than two files.
6. Select the destination folder.
7. Paste (⌘-V)

I was skeptical until I tried it.  It works quite well.

Comment: Surprising. And awesome to know.